Why is this function convex?
I am stuck in understanding the solution of this exercise. We have $f(x) = \begin{cases} 10 & x = 4 \\ x & 4 < x \leq 5 \end{cases}$ where also $f: [4, 5] \to \mathbb{R}$.
The request asks to show the function is convex in $[4, 5]$ and in $(4, 5]$.
In the solution there is written that the use of derivative is useless, and then it says: since $f'(x) = 1$ in $(4, 5)$ this means the function is strictly increasing. Since we have no minimum, but the inf exists and it's $4$, and since $f(x) > 0$ for every $x$ in the domain, we can conclude that $f$ is convex.

I am not sure I got this. It's ok the fact that $f$ is strictly increasing in that interval, but what about $f$ at $x = 4$? I am not sure the function is convex in both $[4, 5]$ and $(4, 5]$.
Also I am not sure about how the inf helps us.

Can you please elaborate a little bit more to help me understanding the solution? Thank you!

Sorry there was a typo, I edited the question.

you can use the definition of function convexity for [4,5]

@goldboy I tried but I am not able to. I know that I have to show $f(ax + (1-a)y) \leq af(x) + (1-a)f(y)$ for two points $x, y$ in the domain, $a \in [0, 1]$. I tried with $x = 4$, $y = 5$ but I got nothing.

$f(x) = x$ is convex. So, we only need to consider the boundary case: $x = 4,\, y\in(4,5]$ and $a\in(0,1)$. Equality trivially holds for $a = 0$ or $1$.
Note that $+(1−) \in (4,5)$, we get
$$(+(1−)) = 4+(1−) ≤ 10+(1−) = ()+(1−)().$$

First, it's easy to see that if $f: X \to Y$ is convex, then so is the restriction of $f$ to any convex $A \subseteq X$, $f|_A: A \to Y$.
Now, taking $X = [4, 5]$, $A = (4, 5] \subseteq X$, and $Y = \mathbb{R}$, we just need to check that $f: X \to Y$ is convex.
Let $x < y \in X$ be arbitrary.

If $x > 4$, then $f (x) = x, f (y) = y$. Clearly, for $t \in [0, 1]$, $4 < x \le t x + (1 - t) y$, then by definition of $f$,

$$f (t x + (1 - t) y) = t x + (1 - t) y = t f (x) + (1 - t) f (y)$$
The equality shows convexity.

If $x = 4$, then $f (x) = f (4) = 10$. For $t \in [0, 1)$, we have that $x = 4 < t x + (1 - t) y$, so that by definition of $f$,

$$f (t x + (1 - t) y) = t x + (1 - t) y = 4 t + (1 - t) y \le 10 t + (1 - t) y = t f (x) + (1 - t) f (y)$$
since $4 t \le 10 t$. If $t = 1$, then $f (t x + (1 - t) y) = f (x) = t f (x)$.
So, for any $x, y \in X$ and $t \in [0, 1]$, we have $f (t x + (1 - t) y) \le t f (x) + (1 - t) f (y)$, as desired.

$f$ is convex if the line segment between any two distinct points on the graph of $f$ lies on or above the graph of $f$.
If both of these endpoints are over $(4,5]$, the line segment coincides with a portion of the graph of $f$; if one of the points is $(4,10)$, the interior points of the line segment lie strictly above the graph of $f$. In either case, the condition for convexity is satisfied.
